# Redirecting database queries to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I have an external service that reads writes to tables in my database. Now I have to change the schema for some new services but I can't update the existing external service, meaning it will still read and write to the same tables as usual.

Without interrupting the old external service while allowing the new services to access my database with a new schema, can it be done as simply as to write up some views with the same old table names but inside the views I do all the mappings to remap old columns according to new table schemas?

Or are there other techniques that can make this task easier?

Comment: For what purpose this new service will be used? Reads or writes or both?

Answer (score 0):

Does the new service has to have the same table name?

I suggest to create a second table as an extension of the old table referenced by foreign key and add to the new columns you require.

Then You'll have to build a view joining the them together to read the data from your application

Comment: No, there is no limitation to the new service and I dont mind to migrate the data from the old tables to new ones.

Comment: You could also build a trigger after insert,update to the new table.